# Customized message post on facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-javascript-sdk, sharing

I have been reading such status updates posted by my friends through some facebook apps.

My total profile views today:123 Male Viewers: 59 Female Viewers: 64 I cant believe that you can see who viewed your Profile! See Who Visit your profile --->

May I know how are such posts made? I tried to do same for my facebook app where users would be sharing  their score on wall, failed every time. 
I am trying to do with HTML/Javascript page and not PHP.

Does such kind of formatting exist?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Mấy cái app nhố nhăng thôi. Chứ FB có cung cấp API để achieve điều đó quái đâu.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you?!